# How to stop Google from logging me out?

Tags: gmail, google-docs, google, google-workspace-for-business

I have a Google Workspace account, every 2 weeks or so it forces me to re-login in the browser (Chrome). For some reason this never happens on my phone. My PCs/Laptops are just as secure if even more secure than my phone. They have a password, they're full disk encrypted, no one but me has access to them and unlike my phone they rarely leave my house so it's really annoying to have to re-login.

Is there a setting somewhere that will stop Google from logging out my accounts every 2 weeks? I have 4 machines I use regularly so this happens on average, every 3.5 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 2 Week Default

By default, the web session length for Google services is 14 days. These settings apply to all desktop web sessions, as well as some mobile browser sessions.

Native mobile apps, like Gmail for Android and iOS, aren’t impacted by these settings.

#### Admins can modify durations

Workspace admins have the ability to specify the duration of web sessions for Google services (e.g. four hours, seven days, or infinite). Unless a user logs out beforehand, they’ll be automatically signed out at the end of that duration and prompted to re-enter their login credentials.

---

#### Instructions

<sup>[support.google.com: Set session length for Google services](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7576830)</sup>

1. Sign in to your [Google Admin console](https://admin.google.com/) (as an admin).
2. Go to **Menu** [image][image: then][image]**Security** [image: then]**Access and data**[image: then]**Google Session control**.
3. On the left, select the organizational unit where you want to set session length.  For all users, select the top-level organizational unit. Otherwise, select another organization to make settings for its users. Initially, an organization inherits the settings of its parent organization.
4. For **Session control**, under **Web session duration**, choose the length of time after which the user has to sign in again.
5. Click **Override** to keep the setting the same, even if the parent setting changes.
6. If the organizational unit's status is already **Overridden**, choose an option:
   **- Inherit:** Reverts to the same setting as its parent.
   **- Save:** Saves your new setting (even if the parent setting changes).

---

Supported editions for this feature: Business Plus; Enterprise; Education Fundamentals, Education Standard, Teaching and Learning Upgrade, and Education Plus; G Suite Business.

Comment: Updated with your suggestion